# How to prevent my injected database from being disposed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have created a class, ObjectBuilder - I am injecting my dbContext into the class constructor and setting it to a read only attribute in the constructor method.
The class has a few different methods that use the dbContext, for example 'CreateorUpdateObject.
In my API controller I am instantiating the ObjectBuilder class. I am then trying to call the 'CreateorUpdateObject' method three times in a row. The first time everything works as intended. The second time, I get an ObjectDisposedException. I understand what this means. However I can't work out how to resolve this issue, seemingly executing a single method will always dispose the context - therefore none of the subsequent methods will work. I am not using any using clauses or disposing of the context myself. Can someone explain to me how to prevent dbContext from dispsoing so I can chain methods.

All the best!

Here is a snippet of the ObjectBuilder Class

```
class ObjectBuilder
{
    readonly GuidObjectBuilder _guidObjectBuilder;
    readonly projectviewerContext _db;
    bool UpdatedGuidsArray { get; set; }
    int UpdatedObjectCount { get; set; }
    int CreatedObjectCount { get; set; }
    ProjectObjects ActiveObject { get; set; }

    public ObjectBuilder(GuidObjectBuilder guidObjectBuilder, projectviewerContext db)
    {
        this._guidObjectBuilder = guidObjectBuilder;
        this._db = db;
        this.UpdatedGuidsArray = false;
        this.UpdatedObjectCount = 0;
        this.CreatedObjectCount = 0;
    }

    public async Task<dynamic> CreateOrUpdateObject(string projectName, string tag, string pidClass, string guId, string fileName)
    {
        //SEND ONE ENTRY RETURNS A PROJECT_OBJECT MODEL
        if (this._db == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("The object builder class has not been set a database. Set the object with a database");
        try
        {
            //Check for an initial entry
            List<ProjectObjects> matchingProjectObjects = (from data in this._db.ProjectObjects.ToList()
                                                            where data.ProjectName == projectName &&
                                                            data.Tag == tag
                                                            select data).ToList();

            if (matchingProjectObjects.Any())
            {
                this.ActiveObject = this.UpdateProjectObject(matchingProjectObjects[0], pidClass, guId, fileName);
                this._db.Update(this.ActiveObject);
                this.UpdatedObjectCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                this.ActiveObject = this.CreateProjectObject(projectName, tag, pidClass, guId, fileName);
                this._db.Add(this.ActiveObject);
                this.CreatedObjectCount++;
            }
            await this._db.SaveChangesAsync();
            if (this.UpdatedGuidsArray)
            {
                //Add new guid
                await this._guidObjectBuilder.CreateOrUpdateUponModelOpen(this.ActiveObject.Id, guId, fileName);
            }
            this.UpdatedGuidsArray = false;
            return this.ActiveObject;
            
        }
        catch (System.Exception error)
        {
            return error;
        }
    }
```

}

Here is a snippet of my test endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/objectCreation/test1")]
    public async Task<dynamic> TestOne()
    {
        try
        {
            projectviewerContext db = new projectviewerContext();
            ObjectBuilder objectBuilder = new ObjectBuilder(new GuidObjectBuilder(db), db);
            await objectBuilder.CreateOrUpdateObject("Project 1", "VV00011", "Gate Valve", "XXCCBBVVNNDDFFHH", "3D_Model.nwd");
            await objectBuilder.CreateOrUpdateObject("Project 1", "VV00012", "Gate Valve", "XXFFGGHHIILLMMNN", "3D_Model.nwd");
            await objectBuilder.CreateOrUpdateObject("Project 1", "VV00014", "Gate Valve", "123456789", "PID_drawing.nwd");
            return "bang";
        }
        catch (System.Exception error)
        {
            return error.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So your UpdateProjectObject and CreateProjectObject don't dispose the dbcontext either? You didn't wrap any calls in a using by accident?

Comment: No - these methods return an single instance of the model. They don't use the db at all.